# Strategy to take cloud (amazon aws) backups

Tags: backup, cloud, database-backup, cloud-storage

I need to take different type of backups(code backup, database backup, user uploaded files backup) from amazon instances, I need to make sure this backups are running properly and if any backup fails I need to get mail (failure is may be because of hacks or server failure)

What currently I am planning is to send mails after every backup to a mail address, and a script will read that mails, if any mail is missing it will shoot a mail to real email address.

I am doing this because I need to maintain different clients web sites backup,

can anybody suggests any better way, basically I am not a sys-admin guy I am a developer who is trying to solve my problem, sys-admins can please suggest any tools or better scripts to do this

Answer (score 1):

I have been using JungleDisk for years on various servers including LAMP servers. It is very reliable and very cost effective. It can also be set up to send you emails every time it does a backup detailing the status of that backup.

http://www.jungledisk.com

Comment: can we configure db backups using this tool

Comment: You will need a script to dump your DBs somewhere into a path that you're backing up. JungleDisk support pre-backup scripts so you can write a simply mysqldump script and tell JungleDisk to call it before it does the backup each night.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutomatiCloud](http://www.automaticloud.net/). It is an easy to use scheduler for backups of AWS EC2 and RDS instances.

With AutomatiCloud you can set up GFS (grandfather-father-son) backup plans with individual retention periods for each level.

It also supports mail notifications.